# Do methods with no operation get compiled out?

Tags: c#, compilation

If I had a method with no operation but to return the passed in parameter would the compiler remove it from the generated MSIL?

For example:

```
public partial class StringResource {

    /// <summary>About</summary>
    public static string About { get { return Encode(Resources.WebUI.About); } }

    public static string Encode(string s) { return s; }
}
```

Would the C# compiler even generate the `Encode` method? How can I look at the generated IL and compare the code with and without the `Encode` method?

And if the static compiler does not remove it what about the runtime JIT compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I had a method with no operation but to return the passed in parameter would the compiler remove it from the generated MSIL?

No. It couldn't be - that would break anything which tried to call that method via reflection, etc.

The method could potentially be inlined to nothing by the JIT, but that's a different matter. There are various things which determined whether methods can be inlined, and those details differ between different versions of the CLR, different process architectures etc. For empty methods, I'd expect them to be inlined (when not running in a debugger) for *non-virtual* calls.

> How can I look at the generated IL and compare the code with and without the Encode method?

1. Compile the code.
2. Disassemble, e.g. with `ildasm Foo.dll /out=before.il
3. Change the code
4. Compile
5. Disassemble, e.g. with `ildasm Foo.dll /out=after.il`
6. Compare `before.il` and `after.il`

Comment: Basically he was asking whether compiler is smart enough to **1.** see that this method practically does nothing and **2.** replace all invocation calls with call parameter... This way there would be no references and no difference in execution. I do understand that compiler doesn't do this, but I wanted to point out because you've stated that it would break calls which it wouldn't if invocations would be replaced as part of optimisation...

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: Well that's not what the question said. The question *actually* asked whether the compiler would remove it from IL, and the answer to that is no, as explained. Note that if it's an instance method, the call site still needs to perform null reference checking.

Comment: Yeah asked the question a little wrong. Not remove the 'Encode' method from the overall generated IL but not include it in the calling  'About' method/

Comment: @BradPatton: I doubt that the C# compiler would do that, although you can check (see my edit). It's generally simpler to let the JIT perform optimization.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Well null ref checks wouldn't be performed if method would be removed and invocations replaced by parameter as part of optimisation. In this case ref checking wouldn't have to check anything because it wouldn't exist. But it's true that if code would be calling method using reflection (and magic strings) it would fail... Breakpoints also wouldn't be hit although VS would show that.

Comment: @JonSkeet compared the code as suggested and it looks like the method is there. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: My point is that if this were an *instance* method call, of the form `foo.Encode` (instead of the static call that it really is) then it would be an *invalid* optimization to remove the call entirely. There would have to be a check that `foo` wasn't null, otherwise it would violate the specified language behaviour.